# Template tag is not working as intended in if-sentence

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have made a very simple template tag which is used to check if the settings file is for production or development. But it seems like i cant use the return value in the if sentence?

My tag:

```
from django.conf import settings

@register.simple_tag
def is_production():
    return settings.SETTINGS_MODE == 'Production'
```

And in my template:

```
{% if is_production %}
....
{% endif %}
```

It is returning True/False in my template when i print the variable `{% is_production %}` but apart from that it does not work in my `if`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: That's not what template tags do. You'd be better off using a context processor to automatically add that variable into the template context.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, can you give an example? Im basically using the variable in my `base.html` which is extended by the actual templates. I don't see any point in making rocket science out of a very simple piece of data i need to distinguish between my production and development code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you have to do:

instead of your templatetag add this in templatetags/my_tag.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

class IsProductionAreaNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist):
        self.nodelist = nodelist

    def render(self, context):
        if settings.SETTINGS_MODE == 'Production':
            return self.nodelist.render(context)
        else:
            return ''


def do_is_production(parser, token):
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endis_production',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return IsProductionAreaNode(nodelist)

register.tag('is_production', do_is_production)
```

now in your template you do following:

```
{% load my_tag %}
.
.
.

{% is_production %}
    *content*
{% endis_production %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a common snippet: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1538/.

But in your case I recommend to set context variable `is_production` in the view.